# Performance overhead of using volatile for setjmp/longjmp

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, setjmp

For **setjmp/longjmp** to work, you need to declare local variables as volatile. If someone is compiling its code with -O3, how much would be the impact of volatile variables on performance . Would it be huge or only a tiny bit on an x86 multicore platform?

In my opinion, it would only add tiny bit of overhead, because that volatile variable could still be cached and reading/writing from cache is quite fast anyway. Opinions?

Comment: Is this likely to be a significant performance hit in your code? If it is, is anything stopping you from measuring performance with and without the `volatile`?

Comment: There is not much general that can be said about that, more than the opinion that you already express. This depends too much of the architecture and of the use pattern. Look into the assembler if there is a lot of load/store going on, compared to the same but non `volatile` code. If you then still don't see clearly, benchmark it, this is the only way to know for sure. Also you only have to declare those variables `volatile` that you will need to change before the `longjmp` *and* access afterwards. To my experience gcc is quite good in detecting these cases.

Comment: Chris, I am talking from a theoretical perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick aside, the semantics of `volatile` all depend on the platform/compiler.  On some compilers like MSVC with IA64 architecture, the `volatile` keyword not only prevents the compiler from re-ordering operations, it also performs each read/write operation with acquire/release semantics, meaning there is a memory-barrier operation in effect.  GCC on the other-hand only prevents the compiler from re-ordering operations before/after the read/write to the volatile memory location ... on platforms with weak-memory models, the acquire-release semantics are not maintained like they are with MSVC.

Now on x86, because of its strict-ordering memory model, the presence of memory barriers from the use of the `volatile` keyword aren't an issue, so the main penalty will simply be the lack of re-ordering and other optimizations that can be performed by the compiler.  That being said, it will then depend on what your code looks like.  For instance, if you have a tight-loop in your code, and certain `volatile`-qualified variables are actually loop-invariants, you're not going to get some of the optimizations that the compiler could do if those memory locations were qualified as non-`volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

The impact depends on the number of local variables and whatever the code does with them. I am sure one could make up an extreme example for a huge impact of `volatile` (e.g. declaring an array of `volatile` variables larger than CPU cache).

It seems that in practice no one wants to maintain code in which all variables have to be `volatile`. That means that the function containing `setjmp` is probably going to be small, probably containing just the `setjmp` stuff. In this case, there will be little or no `volatile` variables, and their "impact" should indeed be small.